# Sharepoint Online: Remove field from a list if the list exceeds the threshold of elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, online, threshold

The list view threshold on Sharepoint Online is set to 5000 and it can't be change. I have a list with more than 7000 items and i need to remove some fields from the list but i get the error that the list has more than 5000 items.

What can i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove those fields programmatically using REST API,Powershell. 
etc,.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-remove-column-from-list-using-powershell.html

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-delete-a-column-in-a-list-using-rest-api-in-sharepoin/

and also meantime, you can hide the field from views if you really can't delete in anyway

Comment: Thanks for your response THIVAGAR SEGAR but the problem persist even trying to delete it programmatically (tried with CSOM and Powershell